# How to implement this(BufferedWriter) using Volley?

Tags: android, android-volley

My code for connection object is --

```
OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                new OutputStreamWriter(os, UTF));
        writer.write(getQuery(params));
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
        os.close();
```

and my getQuery(params) is --

```
public String getQuery(List<NameValuePair> params) throws UnsupportedEncodingException
{
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        boolean first = true;

    for (NameValuePair pair : params)
    {
        if (first)
            first = false;
        else
            result.append("&");

        result.append(URLEncoder.encode(pair.getName(), "UTF-8"));
        result.append("=");
        result.append(URLEncoder.encode(pair.getValue(), "UTF-8"));
    }

    return result.toString();
}
```

Answer (score -2):

This is a bad error-prone practice, try using Retrofit library instead.

Comment: *This is a bad error-prone practice* ... what is so bad practice ... and why? ... .... *try using Retrofit library instead.* why ? and for what?

Comment: Because all url parameter, json forming and parsing is done manually. It can easiy be done by Gson library, which is used with retrodit. By the way, it also support rxJava so you can easily process requests in background.

Comment: But you don't know his needs. what if he want to get binary file? ... then neither gson nor retrofit will help him ...

Comment: Then you should use OkHttp client to send it. You also configure it for Retrofit and can use the same client

Comment: Thanks Alex and Selvin.. I have a simple requirement to replace this api call with Volley as I'm using asynctask in existing code but I'm not sure It's a part of headers or body and from which callback method of volley will be used. So was expecting some clarity ! I have tried in getHeaders() and getBody() of volley but unfortunately it didn't work.